# Does it make a difference to read from a file instead of from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, webserver

My web server currently is quite loaded. And I have a PHP file that is accessed very often remotely. The PHP file basically makes a MySQL query and returns a JSON formatted string.

I am thinking to use a Cron job to write the necessary data into a file every 15 mins, so the PHP file doesn't make a MySQL query, instead it reads from the file.

Does it make a difference? I mean to alleviate the server loading (CPU/MySQL) a bit?

Comment: Yes, of course it will make a difference. You can bench mark this yourself. Also, just consider that SQL allows indexing and relationships etc... How will your file do the same thing? If you've just got "static" data, then maybe XML is a consideration.

Comment: You are probably better off optimizing your query as Dave Rook indicates. Better to have your cron job update a materialized view if your query is in fact that rough. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view

Comment: It sounds as if your script doesn't take any parameters, since you can run it as a CRON job. Also consider simply caching the response in flat file, rather than calling it periodically with CRON.

Comment: My data is not static. They change periodically. So accessing files should have lighter loading than MySQL access right?

Comment: Here is my benchmark info. After changing the PHP to read from a file instead of making a SQL request, MySQL usage time dropped from 11 hours to 4.8 hours, but CPU usage time doesn't change though.

Answer (score 1):

It'll help of course, but your solution isn't really scalable.  For this one case it's a trivial fix, but what do you do when you have 50 files that are affecting performance?

You can't, and shouldn't maintain something like that.In that case you need a better caching mechanism built into your software than an ad-hoc cron job and filesystem cache.

These are the kind of hacks that can eventually build up and make a system unmaintainable.  It's tempting to pursue them because they're easy and can quickly solve a problem.  But you really need to consider if a more permanent solution is better than the quick hack you're proposing.